# Potential difference between DC floating power supply and earth ground

Tags: power-supply, power, oscilloscope, earth, floating

I have a question about a simple DC floating power supply: it is as simple as possible, secondary coil -> bridge rectifier -> filter cap, as shown on the figure below.

[image]

If I connect the input of the oscilloscope between the negative terminal of this simple floating power supply and the earth ground (which is the negative terminal of the oscilloscope input too), I can measure 140 Vpp with the frequency of 50 Hz (figure attached).

[image]

Why is this high amplitude voltage present between these two terminals? Can somebody explain to me the causes of this measurement result?

Comment: parasitic capacitance is a wonderful thing....

Comment: Mistake: the 230VAC supply isn't floating.   Also, every transformer is a capacitor, where the primary coil is one plate, and the secondary coil the second plate.

Comment: Of course, the 230 VAC isn't floating, in this sense the drawing isn't entirely clear. Beside this, to make the description more accurate, I should mention that the power transformer has an electrostatic shield between the primary and the secondary, connected to the earth ground.

Comment: Shield wont matter much for a floating input. Ever hook up just a length of wire to a scope.... AC noise is all around us.

Comment: If you think it is really live.. turn it off, hook in a resistor to ground, turn it on again and check there is no current through the resistor.

Comment: For fun, try attaching the oscilloscope probe (just the tip, not the ground) to yourself! What do you see on the oscilloscope?

Comment: Ok, so the effective impedance - insulation resistance, stray capacitances and the equivalent circuit of measurement system - between earth ground and probe tip, which determines the level of measured voltage.

Comment: All of the above.